How can I put a full-width figure on a partial page in a two column LaTeX document?
I'm trying to include a full-width figure on the last page of my two column document, and LaTeX insists on placing it on a page by itself which looks terrible.
MWE:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{flushend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure*}[tbh]
Test figure
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}



by default figure* only supports t or p so you could use t and move it earlier in the source so it comes at the top of the last page or use a package that provides b and then it can come below the text. (but I'm not sure that is compatibel with flushend, especially if you place the float right at the end which may be too late

@DavidCarlisle I tried this (both with and without flushend), but it also did not work.  It seems like it is resistant to use t on a partially filled page.

a spanning figure always comes at the earliest on teh page after its position in teh source so if you want it on the same page as the text you must move it in the source to be before the first paragraph on that page

It does work with stfloats instead of dblfoaltfix:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{flushend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure*}[b]
Test figure
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}


But indeed, in other cases dblfltfix can be the better solution.
Another solution, i.e., for a one page document could be the usage of midfloat or cuted or multicols:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}

\begin{figure}[b]
Test figure
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


See also Way to span a picture/table across all columns in multicolumn article/report and placing them precisely where they should be.
